# Moving XML Child Nodes to Parent to bottom of The XML(Outside the Current Parent Node)

Tags: xslt

How to move certain Child nodes in a XML file in a one to Many relation with Parent along with its content to the bottom of a xml file outside the parent. 
First for a specifc node and then may be 2 different nodes.

In this example i want to move all Child1 and its content to outside of `<Parent>` and put it below the `</Parent>` and within the `<Control> </Control>`.

```
<Controls>
<Parent ID="1" Prop2="kk">
    ----
            <Child1 ID="1" Prop2="kk1">
                 ------
             </Child1>
             <Child2 ID="1" Prop2="kk2">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
<Parent ID="2" Prop2="kk4">
    ----
            <Child1 ID="11" Prop2="kk5">
                 ------
             </Child1>
             <Child2 ID="11" Prop2="kk6">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
<Parent ID="3" Prop2="kk7">
    ----
            <Child1 ID="111" Prop2="kk8">
                 ------
             </Child1>
             <Child2 ID="111" Prop2="kk9">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
</Controls>
```

Expected Output

```
<MyControls>
<Parent id="1">
    ----
             <Child2 id="1">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
<Parent id="2">
    ----
             <Child2 id="11">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
<Parent id="3">
    ----
             <Child2 id="111">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>

<Child1 id="1">
    ------
</Child1>

<Child1 id="11">
  ------
</Child1>
<Child1 id="111">
   ------
</Child1>
</MyControls>
```

Used XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>      
 <xsl:template match="Child1">
 <Child1>     
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(self::Child1)]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Child1)]" />
 </Child1>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the XML you expect to be output in this case? Also, if you have tried any XSLT, it would help if you showed that too. Thanks!

Comment: Added the expected Output and the XSLT used.

Answer (score 2):

Your stylesheet is a start, but you need more exceptions to prevent the `Child1` elements being copied inside the `Parent`.

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Child1)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Controls">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent/Child1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice that a `Parent` is given special copying, where all descendants but `Child1` are copied. `Controls` is given the explicit ordering of `Parent`s before `Child1`s.

It produces this output when run on your (slightly-modified to fix malformedness) source XML:

```
<Controls>
  <Parent id="1">
    ----

             <Child2 id="1">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
  <Parent id="2">
    ----

             <Child2 id="11">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
  <Parent id="3">
    ----

             <Child2 id="111">
                 ------
             </Child2>
</Parent>
  <Child1 id="1">
                 ------
             </Child1>
  <Child1 id="11">
                 ------
             </Child1>
  <Child1 id="111">
                 ------
             </Child1>
</Controls>
```

New XSLT based on requests in comments:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Controls">
        <MyControls>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent/Child1"/>
        </MyControls>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Parent">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Child1)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@ID">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*[not(name()='ID')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I understand . But what if Child1 can be from any level of child. For example if Child1 is CHild Of Child2 also. How can we change this line <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent/Child1"/> to get Child1 from any level and not only child to Parent.

Comment: This is the problem with giving example XML that doesn’t actually match your use case. What you describe would be matched with `select="Parent//Child1"`, that finds any descendant `Child1`, but I suspect you’ll have yet more exceptions.

Comment: Actually if i just change Parent/Child1 to //Child1 it will work fine.                     ..<xsl:apply-templates select="//Child1"/>

Comment: Yes, that would work too, if `Child1` can be *anywhere*. Your example XML doesn’t give enough information to know where to expect these elements.

Comment: I Agree Buck. Sorry. I could not generalize. But yes the code provided works wonderfully well. Thanks a Ton.

Comment: You’re welcome, glad it helped. If you mark the answer as accepted, others will see you don’t need any further answers.

Comment: Hey Buck. Need to add a little extension to the solution you provided last time. I have revised the original XML. 

Now i have changed the name of the attribute id(lowercase) to ID(UpperCase) in the source XML. 
Further another new attribute of KK1, KK2, KK3... etc has been added on the Parent and Child nodes. 

After the transformation i just want the ID attribute to be copied and not anything else(kk1,kk2,kk3 etc), 

besides i want the ID(Upper) to be renamed into id(Lower) in the transformed XML.

Comment: Further the Root <Controls> tag is to be Renamed to <MyControls> tag.

Comment: @user3657957 - Have you tried making those changes yourself? The are very minor. I've added another stylesheet to this answer that does what you are asking for. Buck Doyle: Feel free to delete/modify it if you want.

Comment: @DanielHaley looks fine to me. Seems like OP doesn’t want to try to understand XSL/XPath haha